# WordPress - Get comments, but exclude some

Tags: wordpress, comments

I'm building a chat box, that pulls comments from a set page. It updates in realtime.

So how can I get the last 50 comments, but exclude the comments I'm already displaying? get_comments() doesn't allow me to exclude comments.

This is what I'd like to be able to do:

```
// Array of already displayed comment id's
$exclude = array(10, 22, 41, 80);

$args = array (
    'number'   => 50,
    'user_id'  => $user_ids,
    'post_id'  => 57,
    'status'   => 'approve',
    'order'    => 'DESC',
    'exclude'  => $exclude
);
$comments = get_comments( $args );
```

Anyone know a way to achieve the 'exclude' parameter, or something equivalent?

Comment: How about filtering (removing comment objects) after retrieval? That would require only one loop.

Comment: How about get comments from database by query ?

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid getting comments from database by query would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ca try raw sql query using wpdb class

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  `wp_comments` 
WHERE `comment_approved` = 1 
  AND `comment_post_ID`=57 
  AND `user_id` IN (0, 1, 2)
  AND comment_ID NOT IN (10, 22, 41, 80)
  ORDER BY  comment_date DESC
  LIMIT 50
```

using [**wpdb**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)

```
global $wpdb
$sql="SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  $wpdb->comments 
WHERE `comment_approved` = 1 
  AND `comment_post_ID`=57 
  AND `user_id` IN (". join(',',$user_ids) .")
  AND comment_ID NOT IN (". join(',',$exclude) .")
  ORDER BY  comment_date DESC
  LIMIT 50";
$comments=$wpdb->get_results($sql);


if(!empty($comments)){
foreach($comments as $c){
$single_comment=get_comment( $c->comment_ID);
}
}
```